# Converting from any base(1-61) to any(1-61) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, base-conversion

I need to write a code, that will translate from any base to any( for 1 base it's Turing machine). I should realize 3 functions using only base library:
1)toDecimal base snumber - convert string number to string decimal number
2)fromDecimal toBase snumber - convert from string decimal to string 1-61 base number
3)convertFromTo fromBase toBase snumber snumber
I made something, but i don't know how can i work with strings (that's my first question, sorry if i made something wrong)
That's the code i made

```
fromDecimal :: Int ->Int-> String
fromDecimal _ 0 = "" 
fromDecimal toBase snumber = fromDecimal toBase (snumber `div` toBase) ++ ["0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" !! k]  
            where k = snumber `mod` toBase
toDecimal :: Int -> String -> Int
toDecimal base []  = 0
toDecimal base _| base<0 = error "Use positeve base"
toDecimal base snumber = letters (last snumber) + base * toDecimal base (init snumber) 
    where letters :: Char -> Int 
          letters ch
                    | ch == '0' = 0
                    | ch == '1' = 1
                    | ch == '2' = 2
                    | ch == '3' = 3
                    | ch == '4' = 4
                    | ch == '5' = 5
                    | ch == '6' = 6
                    | ch == '7' = 7
                    | ch == '8' = 8
                    | ch == '9' = 9
                    | ch == 'a' = 10
                    | ch == 'b' = 11
                    | ch == 'c' = 12
                    | ch == 'd' = 13
                    | ch == 'e' = 14
                    | ch == 'f' = 15
                    | ch == 'g' = 16
                    | ch == 'h' = 17
                    | ch == 'i' = 18
                    | ch == 'j' = 19
                    | ch == 'k' = 20
                    | ch == 'l' = 21
                    | ch == 'm' = 22
                    | ch == 'n' = 23
                    | ch == 'o' = 24
                    | ch == 'p' = 25
                    | ch == 'q' = 26
                    | ch == 'r' = 27
                    | ch == 's' = 28
                    | ch == 't' = 29
                    | ch == 'u' = 30
                    | ch == 'v' = 31
                    | ch == 'w' = 32
                    | ch == 'x' = 33
                    | ch == 'y' = 34
                    | ch == 'z' = 35
                    | ch == 'A' = 36
                    | ch == 'B' = 37
                    | ch == 'C' = 38
                    | ch == 'D' = 39
                    | ch == 'E' = 40
                    | ch == 'F' = 41
                    | ch == 'G' = 42
                    | ch == 'H' = 43
                    | ch == 'I' = 44
                    | ch == 'J' = 45
                    | ch == 'K' = 46
                    | ch == 'L' = 47
                    | ch == 'M' = 48
                    | ch == 'N' = 49
                    | ch == 'O' = 50
                    | ch == 'P' = 51
                    | ch == 'Q' = 52
                    | ch == 'R' = 53
                    | ch == 'S' = 54
                    | ch == 'T' = 55
                    | ch == 'U' = 56
                    | ch == 'V' = 57
                    | ch == 'W' = 58
                    | ch == 'X' = 59
                    | ch == 'Y' = 60
                    | ch == 'Z' = 61
                    | otherwise = error "Wrong number"
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*but i don't know how can i work with strings (that's my first question, sorry if i made something wrong)*"? Exactly what is it you are missing?

Comment: See also [Haskell functions to extract and reverse integers hiding in strings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/24782/23851). (I have the same naming complaint here as there: your "toDecimal" is actually "fromDecimal" and vice versa! (Plus of course you intend to support more than just decimal.)

Comment: What does "for 1 base it's Turing machine" mean?

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is a list of `Char`s. You use some functions like `(++)` and `last` which are not very efficient when working with lists: `(++)` works in linear time with the size of the first list, and `last` will take linear time in the length of the list.

Often when processing lists, the base case is the empty list `[]`, and a pattern `(x:xs)` with `x` the *head* of the list and `xs` the *tail* of th elist matches with *non-empty* lists.

We can define a helper function `go` that will enumerate over the list, and use a parameter (often named an accumulator) that will keep track of the thus far constructed number.

For each element in the list, we first multiply the accumulator with the `base` and then we add the value for the given character. We keep doing that until we reach the end of the list, in which case we return the accumulator:

```
toInt :: Int -> String -> Int
toInt base
    | base <= 0 = error "Invalid base"
    | otherwise = go 0
  where go n [] = n
        go n (x:xs) = go (n * base + letter x) xs

letter :: Char -> Int
letter c
    | '0' <= c && c <= '9' = ord c - ord '0'
    | 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' = ord c - ord 'A' + 10
    | 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' = ord c - ord 'a' + 36
    | otherwise = error "Invalid character"
```

For the `fromDecimal` (perhaps rename it to `fromInt`) you can work with an accumulator as well: in that case you use a list that you each time prepend with a character, and when you reach `0` for the value, you can return that accumulator. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I'd consider doing a toLower or toUpper and eliminate on branch